# $firebaseArray slow loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I'm displaying a $firebaseArray using ng-repeat and $loaded().  However, when that array has started to get bigger, it has started to slow down for the page to load.

I'm posting how I've architect this, so please let me know if you see any ways to do this differently or optimize the process.  I appreciate the help.

In the controller, I first get an array of invoice ids from Firebase.  I send these ids to a service (InvoiceMethods) that then pulls the invoice for each respective id using another service (InvoiceData).  InvoiceMethods also, if it hasn't already previously, pulls the company information for that invoice.

I appreciate the help everyone!

Controller -

```
var createModel = function(){

    // fn that contains any ways i want to filter the invoices
    var fn = function(invoice){
        return true;
    }

    InvoiceMethods.createModel($scope, invoiceTypeIds, fn);
}

invoiceTypeIds = $firebaseArray(ref.child('invoices').child('pending'));  
createModel();
```

In the InvoiceMethods service

```
// creates a model given an array with company and invoice ids
createModel: function($scope, invoiceTypeIds, fn){

  // once arr has finished loading, then structure a local model with co and indiv invoice info
  invoiceTypeIds.$loaded().then(function(){
    $scope.loaded = true;

    // every el represents one company and all the invoices for that company
    invoiceTypeIds.forEach(function(el){

      var invoiceIds = [];

      // get the all the invoice ids for that specific co
      for (var key in el){
        if (key != '$id' && key != '$priority')             
          invoiceIds.push(el[key]);
      }

      // send the company id, array of invoice ids, and any filtering function to get the array of corresponding invoices
      InvoiceData.getIds(el.$id, invoiceIds, fn)

      .then(function(invoicesArr){  

        // remove any invoices that may show up as undefined
        var finalArr = removeUndefined(invoicesArr);

        // if there are any invoices remaining store them in the scope variable under that company id
        if (finalArr.length != 0){
          $scope.invoiceInfo[el.$id] = removeUndefined(invoicesArr);

          // pull the data on that company id, if we haven't already and store in scope variable
          CompanyData.getCo(el.$id).then(function(companyObj){
            if (!$scope.companyInfo[el.$id])
                $scope.companyInfo[el.$id] = companyObj;
          });

        }
      });      
    });
  });

}
```

Finally, we have the getIds function in the service InvoiceData.  This is the function that actually gets the invoices corresponding ID.  It uses a helper function called getInvoices().  I've shown both below.

```
  getIds: function(companyId, invoiceId, fn){
    return getInvoices(companyId, invoiceId, fn);
  }
```

Helper function getInvoices()

```
var getInvoices = function(companyId, invoiceId, fn){
  var promises = [];

  if (invoiceId.constructor == Array){

    invoiceId.forEach(function(el){
        promises.push(search(companyId, el, fn));
    });

    return $q.all(promises);
  }

  else {
    invoiceObj = $firebaseObject(ref.child('invoices').child('originals').child(companyId).child(invoiceId));

    var r = invoiceObj.$loaded().then(function(){
      return invoiceObj;
    });

    return r; 
  }
}
```

Comment: do you actually want to display 8000 elements on the page in the first place?

Comment: its actually 400 objects, but each objects has about 20 properties.  to give you context, they are invoices, with each invoice having properties like date, amount, notes, etc.

Comment: in the context of slow you're talking about 8000 objects?

Comment: the odd thing is that the first time i load the page, its pretty fast.  but then if i flip between another page and back, thats when it slows down.  so why does it load so fast the first time and then slow down the second time?

Comment: to be honest with you there are many different things at play that could all be part of the issue. Your best bet is to strip away the code to the bare bones issue and then post with test code or a very solid description. Stripping away the code to the bare bones problem is also a good debugging strategy anyway. I would post again once you have narrowed down the code to as simple and specific as you can get that is easily replicated.

Comment: thanks.  will try that.

Comment: There is not a lot we can do here except say "reduce the size of your data" or "get a better connection", both of which are pretty generic as advice. If you'd like better help, post a [minimal piece of code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Even better (since it makes it easier for us to test the code) is if you reproduce your problem in a minimal, functional jsfiddle/jsbin.

Comment: Hey @tommybananas and Frank, I've updated the question with the code.  Please let me know if you have any ideas.  Again, I appreciate the help.